# Como substituir vogais por @

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo uma tarefa da faculdade que pede um programa onde o usuário digita a string [20] e eu retorno pra ele a string invertida e com as vogais substituídas por @s.

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa? O quê? Coloque o código na pergunta, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu pensei nesta solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char vogais[] = {'a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','u','U'};
char texto[20] = "stAckovErflow";
int i,j;

//substituindo as vogais
for(i=0; i < strlen(texto); i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < strlen(vogais); j++)
    {
        if(vogais[j] == texto[i])
        {
            texto[i] = '@';
        }
    }
}

//invertendo a String
strrev(texto);
//imprimindo no console
printf("%s\n", texto);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou muito! Código simples e compreensível, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Strings em C são arrays de caracteres. Use um `for` com um contador `i` para percorrer cada posição. Em cada iteração do `for`, você pega a letra na posição `i` e compara ela com `'a'`, com `'e'`, com `'i'`, com `'o'` e com `'u'`. Se uma dessas comparações for verdadeira (use o `||`), então você troca o caracter na string por um `'@'`. Você vai ter que comparar tanto as vogais minúsculas quanto as maiúsculas.

Depois você usa um outro `for` para inverter a string, ele vai percorrer posições `i` do começo da string até o meio, então você troca o caractere da posição `i` com a da posição `n - i - 1`, onde `n` é o tamanho da string.

Answer (score 0):

Para substituir as vogais por '@' , percorre-se array de caracteres(str), para cada caractere verifica se é igual a uma vogal  (str[i] == vogais[v]), atribuindo o @ no indice que se encontra a vogal(  str[i] = '@' )

no exemplo abaixo, o resultado é 'st@ck@v@rfl@w' para str = "stackoverflow";

```
int main()
{

    char vogais[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    char str[20] = "stackoverflow";
    for(int i =0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        int vogal=0;
        for(int v =0; v<5; v++){
            if(str[i] == vogais[v]) vogal= 1;
        }
        if(vogal == 1){
            str[i] = '@';
        }
    }
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```